# Extract a single file / directory from a .dar file

Tags: archive, data-extraction

No, it's not a mistake, I mean [`dar`](http://dar.linux.free.fr/), not `tar`.
It seems to be a not-so-popular archiving tool (and file format). However, I need to extract a single directory from a 4GiB .dar-file.

In the man-page, dar lists a whole bunch of options of which I've tried `-I` (`--include <mask>`). However, it seems to work on filenames without their path. I am overwhelmed by the number of options.

Answer (score 3):

While typing my question and reading the `man` page more thoroughly, it came to me that the answering flag is `-g`, so to extract from an archive a single directory into the current one, use:

```
dar -x archive-name -g dir/to/extract
```

According to the man page, `dar` features six different parameters for file selection, namely `-I` vs `-X`, `-P` vs `-g` and `-[` vs `-]`.

The interesting one to this question has the following description:

> ```
>   -g, --go-into <path>
> ```
>
> Files or directory to only take in account, as opposed to -P. -g may
>   be present several time on command-line. Same thing here, the
>   difference with  -I  is  that  the  mask  is applied to the
>   path+filename and also concerns directories. By default all files
>   under the -R directory are considered. Else, if one or more -g option
>   is given, just those are selected (if they do not match any -P
>   option). All paths given this way must be relative to the -R
>   directory. This is equivalent as giving  out of any option.
>   **Warning**, -g option cannot receive wildcards, these would not be interpreted.